# error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

App crashed in the 2nd NSLog line.

Debug statement:
(lldb) po textView.superview
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
(lldb)

Can you tell me what could be the problem.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:AlertContentSizeKeyPath]) {
        UITextView * textView = object;
        NSLog(@"textView :: %@", textView);
        NSLog(@"bounds :: %f", [textView bounds].size.height);
        CGFloat topCorrect = ([textView bounds].size.height - [textView contentSize].height * [textView zoomScale])/2.0;
        topCorrect = ( topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect );
        textView.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topCorrect};
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: u were allocating the memory of uitextview or not

Comment: Are you sure `object` is actually a text view? Are you sure `textView` is not `nil`?

Comment: @Anbu, No i'm not allocating

Comment: just initialize  the memory of textviw after that convert the object to ur textview

Comment: Hi All, found the mistake. KVO only observe objects properties. Here i was trying to access objects instead of object's property. The third line should be UITextView * textView = ((controller *)object).alertTextView